# RESTful API related objects & denormalization (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, rest, database-design, architecture, denormalization

I'm building a RESTful web application using node.js and MongoDB.

I have a **Person model**

```
Person
  id:         '12345'
  name:       'John'
  likes:      [ {id: '54321', name: 'Mary'} ]
  isLikeydBy: []


Person
  id:         '54321'
  name:       'Mary'
  likes:      []
  isLikeydBy: [ {id: '12345', name: 'John'} ]
```

**What is the best way to model "likes" and "isLikedBy" relationships?** Since I am using MongoDB I thought that this is a good way to model the relationships, as there is only one access to database needed to get all data about one person.

**How to create a REST api for this relationship?** What if 'John' doesn't like 'Mary' anymore. The server only receives the following put request.

```
  Person
  id:         '12345'
  name:       'John'
  likes:      []
  isLikeydBy: []
```

But the server should also update 'Mary', because now she is not liked by 'John' anymore. (I know that MongoDB does not directly support transactions and that I have to implement them myself.)

**My ideas:**

**1.** On each update of Person (of it's 'likes' and 'isLikedBy' fields) get this person from database and compare their 'likes' and 'isLikedBy' fields with the request. There is some overhead with this approach and also I do not know if it is in the spirit of RESTful APIs.

**2.** Make the client send both the original 'likes' and 'isLikedBy' fields and also the new updated ones (or only the diff). This seems even further away from RESTful design, since  the client must now be aware of which data was last successfully saved to the server.

**3.** Create a separate object which would contain the relationship information (3 fields: id, me, whoILike). But this means that each time I would want to get data about a person I would need 2 queries, one for the person and one for relationships and then combine the data into single object.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

We've wrestled with this same problem at my company when using Mongo and tracking likes.

After much discussion we decided to store the counts of likes with the entities - in this case storing likes with people.

Opinions on your options:

1. The overhead in doing additional queries is probably a bad idea. Especially since "liking" stuff is seen by the users as a lightweight operation. In other words, you might find users liking a ton of stuff, which means a lot of writes - and in this case every write has an additional read or two with it.
2. This is a lot of work for the developer to do and it's easy to get wrong.
3. I think it's ok, but I still prefer to store likes with the person. Mongo isn't good at joins like you mentioned.

I think you should store the like/liked by fields with the person document. The only thing I would change is the REST call being made.

Maybe something like:

`PUT http://www.rest.com/person/123/likes/456`

This would say "Person 123 likes 456." Then your REST call makes sure the data is updated.  It would update the Person 123 object *and* the Person 456 object.

To remove something like:

`DELETE http://www.rest.com/person/123/likes/456`

Keep in mind every time someone makes a REST call, the update doesn't have to update the entire document. You can do partial updates on the Person document with the modified likes. You can also easily add/remove an array in a document.